# How to delete a tree in C# Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, entity-framework-core

I have a `Category` `class`, which has `List<Category>`. So it makes a tree kind of structure like `Category` then multiple subcategories then again multiple subcategories under it and so on.

I want to delete this whole tree, I have implemented the below method, but it's not working as expected.

```
public async Task DeleteCategoryById(int Id)
{
    CategoryDto category = new CategoryDto();
    var details = _categoryRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Id == Id);

if (details == null)
{
 return;  
}
var children = (_categoryRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.ParentId == Id));
int childCount = children.Count();

if (childCount != 0 )
{
    category.Category = ObjectMapper.Map<List<CategoryDto>>(children);
}

if (category.Category == null)
{
   await _categoryRepository.DeleteAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
}
else
{
    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
      await  DeleteCategoryById(category.Category[i].Id);
    }
}
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool IsLast { get; set; } = true;
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "but it's not working as expected." What does it do?

Comment: Its not deleting the whole tree, its deleting only few categories

Comment: Move `await _categoryRepository.DeleteAsync(x => x.Id == Id);` to the end of the method (unconditionally after deleting children). Currently you are deleing recursively just the leaf children.

Comment: Isn't the cascade deletion enabled by default in EF Core on _context.SaveChanges() ?

Comment: @Dimitar Actually I dont want cascade deletion. Because in some other cases, deletion login will be different

Comment: In sql, all you had to do is use a foreign key with `on delete cascade`. I know almost nothing about EF, but I should imagine that it should have a similar option built in...

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right, but in other cases of deletion, I don't want cascade delete. This is one case where I need cascade delete.

Comment: @IvanStoev it worked. Thanks, you always rock.

Comment: @ZoharPeled SqlServer (hence EF) does not allow cascade delete for self referencing tables (multiple cascade paths).

Comment: @IvanStoev but why it doesn’t allow? Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: @viveknuna Because they decided not to. For instance, Oracle has no such limitation. And since SqlServer is MS product, they apply that rule to all their frameworks (EF, EF Core etc.)

Comment: @IvanStoev I didn't know that, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Ivan Stoev for your suggestions, it worked for me.

Moving `await _categoryRepository.DeleteAsync(x => x.Id == Id);` to the end of the method (unconditionally after deleting children). I was deleting recursively just the leaf children.

Answer (score 1):

> 1st Option: In your context class you should enable on delete cascade behavior:

Example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
   .HasMany(c => c.Category)
   .WithOne(e => e.Category).
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade );
}
```

**OR**

> 2nd Option: Delete the childrem first, and then delete the main category

Comment: Its comment not an answer, and Its already been suggest in the above comments